# How to use threads in Python to limit database connections

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import logging
from typing import List, Union

import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import json
import sys


class MySQLQuery:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        # Read the configuration file and get database connection information
        with open("config.json", 'r') as file:
            config = json.load(file)

        self.mysql_db = config['mysql']
        
        # Create and configure a logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # Create a file handler and set the formatter
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler("mysql_query.log")
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        # Add the file handler to the logger
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    def print_db_name(self):
        print(list(self.mysql_db.keys()))

    def get_db_info(self, database: str) -> dict:
        
        # Retrieve the database connection information based on the provided database name
        database_info_result = self.mysql_db.get(database)
        return database_info_result

 
    def get_dataframe(self, database: str, queries: Union[str, List[str]]) -> Union[pd.DataFrame, dict]:
       
        if isinstance(queries, str):
            # If a single query is provided, execute it and return the DataFrame
            return self._execute_query(database, queries)
        elif isinstance(queries, list):
            # If a list of queries is provided, execute them and return the dictionary of DataFrames
            results = {}
            for i, query in enumerate(queries):
                result_df = self._execute_query(database, query)
                results[f"result{i+1}"] = result_df
            return results
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid input for 'queries'. It should be either a single SQL query (str) or a list of SQL queries (List[str]).")

    def _execute_query(self, database: str, query: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
        
        # The internal method to execute a single SQL query and return the result as a DataFrame
        info = self.get_db_info(database)
        host = info['host']
        user = info['user']
        password = info['pass']
        port = info['port']

        try:
            # Open a database connection
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, port=port)

            # Create a cursor to execute the query
            cursor = cnx.cursor()

            # Execute the SQL query and fetch the result
            cursor.execute(query)
            result = cursor.fetchall()

            # Get column names
            column_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]

            # Convert the result to a DataFrame
            result_df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=column_names)

        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f"Connection failed: {e}")
            result_df = pd.DataFrame()  # Return an empty DataFrame if an error occurs

        finally:
            # Close the database connection
            cursor.close()
            cnx.close()
            self.logger.info("Connection ended")

        return result_df
```

This is a class for connecting to the database. 
I am facing an issue where the connection takes a long time for a simple query.
I want to limit the time it takes to establish a connection.

I have already tried some methods, but they didn't work as expected. 
My goal is to ensure that the connection completes within 30 seconds.

```
import time
import threading
from SQL_Connect import MySQLQuery

database_name = 'data'
query = """select *
            from XXX
        """

def A():
    print("A starts")
    time.sleep(30)
    print("A ends")

def B(database_name, query):
    print("B starts")
    mysql_query = MySQLQuery()
    result = mysql_query.get_dataframe(database_name, query)
    print("B ends")
    return result

thread_A = threading.Thread(target=A)
thread_B = threading.Thread(target=B, args=(database_name, query))

thread_B.setDaemon(True)

thread_A.start()
thread_B.start()


thread_A.join()
```

This is the result. 
This query definitely cannot finish within 30 seconds. 
So, the result is not as expected.

```
DeprecationWarning: setDaemon() is deprecated, set the daemon attribute instead
  thread_B.setDaemon(True)
A starts
B starts
B ends
C:\Python310\lib\threading.py:953: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MySQLQuery.get_dataframe' was never awaited
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
A ends
```

Comment: You may need to review the documentation for MySQLQuery. Having said that, it might help if you write your own class to manage the database connection and queries. That way you will only have to connect once and just re-use the connection